# How do I display a single item in a new activity from a ListView of multiple items (Android)

Tags: android, listview, rss, android-activity

If you have any knowledge of ListViews/RSS feeds/Android programming in general, please take a quick look at this question.  Thanks!

I have a ListView of multiple items(messages) that are listed in my NewsActivity as follows:

```
public class NewsActivity extends ListActivity {
private List<Message> messages;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news);
    loadFeed();
}

private void loadFeed(){
    try{
        BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
        messages = parser.parse();
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
        List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
        for (Message msg : messages){
            titles.add(msg.getTitle());
            descriptions.add(msg.getDescription());
            dates.add(msg.getDate());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titles);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Throwable t){
        Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RSSItem.class);
    //id = the id of the item clicked
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    int count = 0;
    for (Message msg : messages) {
        if(count == id){
                 //This is obviously not how it should be done.
                 //But my idea here is that I need to pass the msg to the new RSSItem class.
                 RSSItem item = new RSSItem(msg);
            }
            count++;
    }
}
}
```

This NewsActivity displays my ListView of the titles of each message.  The part I need help with is the last function onListItemClick.  The function creates a new RSSItem Activity.  I just need to display the title, date, and description of that item(which are all currently saved in Lists) in this new activity.  Here is what I have so far for the RSSItem class:

```
public class RSSItem extends Activity {
private Message rssItem;
private String title;
private String date;
private String description;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rssitem);

}

public RSSItem(){
    //default constructor: must have 0 arguments
}
public RSSItem(Message msg){
    rssItem = msg;
    title = rssItem.getTitle();
    date = rssItem.getDate();
    description = rssItem.getDescription();
}
}
```

So... currently, RSSItem gets the message from the NewsActivity, and saves the title, date, and description.  If this should be done in a better/different way, please let me know.

Now I just need to display this information(title, date, description) in this new RSSItem Activity. However, I am not exactly sure how this works/how to do it.  Is it completely determined by the R.layout.rssitem file?  Here is my R.layout.rssitem file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/description" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Currently, the RSSItem Activity doesn't display anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the easiest thing to do is to add extra's to your Intent before calling startActivity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, RSSItem.class);
//pardon the gross use of fields and key names.
//you would pass in the selected item's fields, more than likely using
//its position, not id
i.putExtra("title", title);
i.putExtra("description", description);
i.putExtra("date", date);

startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Then in your onCreate() in the RSSItem Activity, you can retrieve that intent by

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rssitem);

    Intent receivedIntent = this.getIntent();
    //and pick up the extras
    title = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("title");
    //and so on...

    //instantiate views...
    TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleView.setText(title);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post! This works perfectly.  The title, date, and description can now be used in this new activity.  However, do you know how to display these now? (It is still displaying nothing).  I know that I can do something like SetContentView(title), etc. but I don't want to manually do this.  Is there a way to do it by using the layout.rssitem file?  Or how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You may need to have a look at some more basic examples... but the idea will be after calling setContentView(R.layout.rssitem), to instantiate the views from your layout so they can show what you want them to. I modified the post slightly to give a general idea.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see now.  I looked at some similar examples, and actually had something like that before.  That's exactly what I need though. Thanks so much for your help!